# What does it mean to dominate an enemy?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

There are 2 achievements for dominating an enemy (and a bunch more involving killing enemies who are dominating):

- **Repeat Offender:** Dominate an enemy
- **Decimator:** Dominate ten enemies

Some how, I am at 2/10 for Decimator, but I do not have the Repeat Offender achievement, what exactly does dominating an enemy entail?

Comment: In both CS:S and TF2 it's killing one guy 4 times without him killing you. I'm assuming it'll be something similar, but I haven't played it.

Comment: I'd assume that the achievement is glitched - if you got even 1/10 on Decimator, it seems like you should've gotten Repeat Offender.  Not 100% sure on this, so this is a comment :)

Comment: it certainly looks glitched to me, I don't know how I can be 2/10 and not have the first one, but I wasn't quite sure what dominate means though @MrSmooth's comments makes a lot of sense

Comment: since CS:GO is still in beta... submit a bug to Valve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like in other Source based games, dominating an enemy in Counterstrike: Global Offensive simply means killing an enemy four times without them killing you once.

Comment: also it means killing someone 4 times without them killing you or getting an assist on you once.